# Ionic app with tabs + "global" search header

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I've created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/w7JwxNF140NCSAnGpfnQ?p=preview) showing my scenario. Please take a look.

The issue is that when I click *search input* I get redirected to **offers tab**. This shouldn't happen. When I click *search input* in **home tab**, search should be shown inside **home tab** and not **offers tab**.

If I click *search input* in **offers tab**, search should be shown inside **offers tab** and not **home tab**.

Navigation is therefore messed up in my example.

**Tabs**

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

  <ion-tab title="Home" icon-off="ion-ios-home-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-home" ui-sref="app.home">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-home"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Promoções" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" ui-sref="app.offers">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-offers"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

**States**

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'main.html',
            controller: function(){}
        });

        $stateProvider
            .state('app.search', {
                url: '/search',
                views: {
                    'tab-home': {
                        templateUrl: 'search.html',
                        controller: function($scope, $state){
                      $scope.current = $state.current;
                      $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState){
                        $scope.current = toState;
                      });
                    }
                    },
                    'tab-offers': {
                        templateUrl: 'search.html',
                        controller: function($scope, $state){
                      $scope.current = $state.current;
                      $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState){
                        $scope.current = toState;
                      });
                    }
                    }
                }
            });

            $stateProvider
            .state('app.offers', {
                url: '/promos',
                views: {
                    'tab-offers': {
                        templateUrl: 'offers.html',
                        controller: function($scope, $state){
                          $scope.current = $state.current;
                          $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState){
                            $scope.current = toState;
                          });
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            $stateProvider
            .state('app.home', {
                url: '/home',
                views: {
                    'tab-home': {
                        templateUrl: 'home.html',
                        controller: function($scope, $state){
                          $scope.current = $state.current;
                          $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState){
                            $scope.current = toState;
                          });
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

**My goal is**:

- When clicking search input and the current tab is home, then open search in the home tab.
- When clicking search input and the current tab is offers, then open search in the offers tab.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You will call the openSearch() in onfocus and openSearch() function do the state change thats the reason for switch the tabs while click on search bar.

Comment: You have two tabs for app.search i.e 'tab-home' & 'tab-offers' and 'tab-offers' is the latest.  that is the main reason. Your view should be associated to only one tab at the same time.

Comment: I've edited my question adding what is my goal. So I can't associate my state with 2 view? So how can I accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 0):

You really should make the search part children of the individual tabs so you can replace them

Comment: Search is just an example, but almost all my states would behave like this. I would have 4~5 main tabs and all other states would be rendered in the active tab. I've tried to make search children of 2 tabs, however `state.go('app.search')` would not work and I cannot use `state.go('app.home.search')` or `state.go('.search')`, because I can go to *search* from anywhere... I want to just use `state.go('app.search')`. I was studying how ui-router renders views.. do you have any insights of how to implement such thing? This is how *facebook iOS* app navigation works. I'm just trying to mimic it.

Comment: perhaps you need to rethink how you are doing this and use directives instead?

Comment: ok, I get that what I'm doing is wrong... but how to accomplish this? I mean, is this possible? How I would use directives to accomplish this, where should I add such directive? I mean, I'm trying to understand which point of ui-router I have to change.